whatsapp-web.js not sending video (nothing happens )
I am struggling with the sendMessage method of whatsapp web js. Here is my test code:
import pkg from 'whatsapp-web.js';
const { Client, LocalAuth, MessageMedia } = pkg;
import qrcode, { error } from 'qrcode-terminal';


const client = new Client({ 
    puppeteer: {
        executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
    },
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth({ dataPath: "sessions", }), 
    webVersionCache: { 
        type: 'remote', 
        remotePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/main/html/2.2412.54.html', 
    }
});


client.on('qr', qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
});

client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log('Pret'); 
    const media = await MessageMedia.fromUrl('https://runex-fitness.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/Elegant-Beige-Launching-Soon-Instagram-Reel-2-1.mp4');
    await client.sendMessage("120363276528243349@g.us", media);
});

client.on('message_ack', (message, ack) => {
    console.log(`Message ack received: ${ack}`);
    // ack sera true si le message a été envoyé avec succès
});

client.initialize();


When the Url MessageMedia.fromUrl is for an image, it work, for a gif it work (but send the gif as a image), but for a video nothing happen.
I use a 2020 macbook pro m1.
I tried all the solutions found (the main was adding the executablePath to puppeteer, but it fo not change anything, the problem continue to occurs.
Impossible to send a video of 5mb, even if the file is hosted on local.
I want to be able to send a video.

Same bug here, did someone find the solution?!

Yes, I found a solution.

https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/3002

Please use the fixed version mentioned in issue #3002 (https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/3002) as your remotePath like so:
remotePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guigo613/alternative-wa-version/main/html/2.2412.54v2.html' 

For some reason the JS for processing the video was no longer able to be loaded for the other versions.
